# any open source library for PDF reader

Tags: iphone

**QUESTION UPDATE**

Their is any alternative of fastPDF reader for iphone app. Or any open source library which we can use full in pdf reader feature.

Thanks.

Comment: there are three options: buy a FastPdfKit license choosing from Basic, Plus and Extra versions.

Comment: hi , did you got the solution to remove the logo of fastPDF and if yes how did you solved it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three options: buy a FastPdfKit license choosing from Basic, Plus and Extra versions

Comment: make sure that the bundle id and license key combination matches after purchasing the license.

Answer (score 2):

instead of that you can show any loding... image and present it for 5 seconds. so no one will see the fastpdf logo.

Answer (score 1):

You can sublass MFDocumentViewController and hide the splash screen by hiding the child Image View:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)   {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            // hide the splash screen
            view.hidden = YES;
        }
    }];
}
```

But before publishing your app, carefully check first the license. I think the free license is an attribution license, so just leaving out the splash screen won't do it